# Is there any method to bring back my old deleted question to edit?

Tags: support, edits, deleted-questions, post-ban

I accidentally deleted my question. I can't currently change it because I am now question banned, but the question helper is telling me to edit my question in order to get approval. How can I get my old question in an editable state?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/54109443) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/52882181) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/52615448) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/52598054) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/51840562) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/47369563) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/46023454))

Comment: It seems you're in a *serious* need to read [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Ask good questions, not bad ones. I have a strong feeling that many of your deleted questions have close votes on them, though they should have already expired.

Comment: I modifed the #1 question. Who will see it because the system say If I want to undelete the post I should get 4 undelete vote but If nobody see who vote up?

Comment: @Akos.prestigio any high-rep user can see your question